# write width and height of an image in txt file with batch

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, command-line, ffmpeg

How to save image size (width and height) in new file using ffmpeg or irfanview?

I want it to be saved like this:

```
img.png 800 600
img2.png 640 480
....
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are prepared to use ImageMagick, which is free and available for Windows, you can achieve your goal with this

```
identify -format "%f %w %h\n" *png  > someFile.txt
```

**Output**

```
baddies.png 500 500
bar.png 4422 480
blobs.png 500 500
board.png 100 100
datebar.png 100 60
explain.png 1769 480
```

By the way, Windows Notepad and others may work better with Windows-style line-endings, so you could replace `\`n in my answer with `\r\n` to make them happier.